# Baby with ASD VSD PDA altogether

Tags: cardiology, cardiovascular-disease, ventricular-spetal-defect, atrial-septal-defect-asd

If a baby has ASD VSD and PDA altogether, than what are the chances for his self-recovery without any heart surgery. Also how soon would you expect such a recovery?

What are the things you would watch in his echo or other tests, to verify if self-recovery is happening?